# Union of return types within nested objects

Tags: typescript

I have an TypeScript object whose properties contain another object which all contain function properties. i.e. it conforms to this interface:

```js
interface ObjectOfFunctions {
    [key: string]: Function;
}

interface ObjectOfObjectsOfFunctions {
    [key: string]: ObjectOfFunctions;
}
```

I'm trying to create a type that expresses the union of all of the return types of those inner functions.

I've managed to get it working for a single object, using the following:

```js
export type PropertyReturnTypes<T> = T[keyof T] extends ((a: any) => any) ? ReturnType<T[keyof T]> : never;
```

But I can't figure out how to make it work with the outermost object (`ObjectOfObjectsOfFunctions`). Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you provide a usage example with expected output for this hypothetical type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the return type of all nested function, one level deep, you can use a mapped type to get all the types return types for each nested objects using your `ObjectOfFunctions` type. You can then get a union of all of these types using another indexing operation:

```
export type PropertyReturnTypes<T> = T[keyof T] extends ((a: any) => any) ? ReturnType<T[keyof T]> : never;

export type NestedPropertyReturnTypes<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: PropertyReturnTypes<T[P]>
}[keyof T];


type R = NestedPropertyReturnTypes<{
    o: {
        f1: () => "f1"
        f2: () => "f2"
    },
    o2: {
        f2: () => "f2"
        f3: () => "f3"
    },
}>
// Same as 
// type R = "f1" | "f2" | "f3"
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKUItogSsGAVygDsAVZYAZwB4yA+OAXjjIG0BrYRCAM1YC6cUDGAkAJlTgAKaQEMAXHDklEASmaMV6uAH44+IqQoo6nbn0GMlJYADdgUANwAoF6EiwElOADlqouIYWI5IhsTklLQMzHAA3i5wSXBsaHAAliRwXDz8ZAJKwdhhBBEm1GZoAvQuAL7muYKubkgoBrH+VIFFoXilxlE0CclwEErDI8m8AIxK0hpMjABEM0uJk0m8AExzC8vbayO1ADTrSRA78WeT27uacCtbhxtwvADMd4sP789JJ3U1AD0gLgAGU5ABbVByKQuYHeNq4WIraZLOAAH2+Twx3zeSyAA)

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you so much!